# Connect IC without Pins to Breadboard

Tags: integrated-circuit, breadboard

How to connect a IC without pin to breadboad? i have a 32 pin IC, any help on how to connect to my circuit in Breadboard.
Thanks.

Comment: You need what's called a breakout board. Solder your IC to that, and the breakout board's pins will go into the breadboard.

Comment: Alternatively you can use a breakout board with a ZIF socket.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to electronics/Circuit.. That was helpful.

Comment: BM1397 is the IC I am trying to build circuit. If possible can you suggest a breakout board. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Sundar If I am seeing the right chip, BM1397 is a 7 nm high-speed cryptoprocessing chip intended for cryptocurrency mining. That was *crucial* info not included in the original question, so the comments above may not apply now. I suspect that this chip requires specific high-speed connections and careful PCB/underlying system design, and a breakout board isn't going to work reliably or at all. You'll also need the datasheet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nanofarad.